# Lazy proxies through interfaces (entities with final methods)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy, hibernate-mapping

I have a requirement in my project that all my methods should be either abstract or final (please don't argue this requirement -- I know it's dumb, just assume it's there).

This is a problem with Hibernate mapped entities since Hibernate needs to create proxies in run-time in order to be able to initialize relations when those are lazily loaded. Not being able to override setter methods results in those not being loaded at all (query is indeed executed, but the object is never populated).

As stated in [Hibernate's documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-pojo-final):

> If the final class does implement a proper interface, you could alternatively tell Hibernate to use the interface instead when generating the proxies. See Example 4.4, “Proxying an interface in hbm.xml” and Example 4.5, “Proxying an interface in annotations”.

Example:

```
 @Entity @Proxy(proxyClass=ICat.class) public class Cat implements ICat { ... }
```

So theoretically it's possible to just tell hibernate to implement an interface instead of extending the original class.

I've tried this solution, but my problem comes with the relations themselves. Here's an over-simplified example:

```
@Entity
@Proxy(proxyClass = ICat.class)
@Table(name = "cat")
public class Cat implements ICat {

    @Id
    private Long catId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cat", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Kitten> kittens;

    ...
}


@Entity
@Proxy(proxyClass = IKitten.class)
@Table(name="kitten")
public class Cat implements IKitten {

    @Id
    private Long kittenId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="catId")
    private Cat cat;

    ...
}
```

Now if I try to obtain a `Cat` object, I get a `ClassCastException` since it is trying to cast an `IKitten` collection into a `Kitten` collection. Which leads me to think I should declare relations using interfaces instead of implementations -- which also produces a compilation-time error since my Interfaces are never declared as entities, but the implementations are (which is clearly stated in the example from the documentation).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You con use the interface in both `one-to-many` and `many-to-one` associations, but you need to supply the actual Class in the `targetEntity` attribute. The relations should be something like this:

```
@Entity
@Proxy(proxyClass = ICat.class)
@Table(name = "cat")
public class Cat implements ICat {

    @Id
    private Long catId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cat", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Cat.class)
    private List<IKitten> kittens;

    ...
}


@Entity
@Proxy(proxyClass = IKitten.class)
@Table(name="kitten")
public class Cat implements IKitten {

    @Id
    private Long kittenId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="catId", targetEntity=Cat.class)
    private ICat cat;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement before, and bypassed it by declaring final all classes. My hibernate structure was not proxying, and thus I don't know if that will fix the problem, but the requirement. There is a side problem if you are using mockito. Have this in mind.

By the way, there is a typo in the second class shown in your code, it shall be named Kitten